# launchWebAuthFlow with Spotify returns "Authorization page could not be loaded"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, spotify, google-chrome-app, spotify-app

I registered my app on Spotify. I made sure I had the URI added to my registered app. But still every time I run this code I keep getting the same error. I am also running this in the background so I know it's not that. What am I doing wrong?

Also I tried switching `/spotify` with `/provider_cb`.

```js
var client_id = '<my_client_id>';
var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL() + "/spotify";

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id="+client_id+
         "&redirect_uri="+ encodeURIComponent(redirectUri) + 
         "&response_type=token", 
  'interactive': true,  
},
function(redirect_url) { 
  console.log(redirect_url);
});
```

Here are my permissions:

```js
"permissions": [
  "http://*/*", "tabs", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "storage", "identity",
  "declarativeContent", "https://accounts.spotify.com/*",  
  "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/*"
]
```

On the first time I run my app after restarting Chrome, the sign-in page pops up like everything is fine, but after I log in I still get the same error:

```
identity.launchWebAuthFlow: Authorization page could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Try removing the `/` from the permission URL so it's `"https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize*"`.

Comment: didn't make a difference :(

Comment: Why do you append `"/spotify"` to `redirectUri`? You may want to try without.
Moreover, `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` returns something like https://hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki.chromiumapp.org/ so you might have an issue with double slashes there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("spotify");
```

`getRedirectUrl` will return a url with a / at the end. so your original code was resulting in:

```
"https://<app_id>.chromiumapp.org//spotify"
```

Instead you can pass endpoint as an argument to form url

Answer (score 1):

The `getRedirectURL` method has an overload for path so you don't need to add the string.

```
var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('spotify')
```