# Google OAuth2: get token ID

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I have an Android application which uses Google sign and sends the token ID to the server. So, the server identifies the user by the token ID.

I also have a Chrome extension and I would like to find the token ID but I cannot find anyway for doing so.
I think the extension should bring the user through the OAuth authentication process like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542159/google-oauth2-get-token-javascript-post-request). Unfortunately that procedures fails with: **Authorization page could not be loaded**

These are the scopes I'm setting in the manifest:

- openid
- email
- profile

That would be so easy if there would be a Google web service which returns the token ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) API to get OAuth2 access tokens. The [`getAuthToken`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) gets an OAuth2 access token using the client ID and scopes specified in the [`oauth2 section of manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#update_manifest).

For the error **Authorization page could not be loaded**, try removing the `/` from the permission URL.

Check these links:

- [launchWebAuthFlow with Spotify returns "Authorization page could not be loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445656/launchwebauthflow-with-spotify-returns-authorization-page-could-not-be-loaded)
- [How get Facebook token using Oauth2 with chrome.identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312547/how-get-facebook-token-using-oauth2-with-chrome-identity)
- [How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest)